# How to get number in international format from call history

Tags: android, phone-number, calllog, libphonenumber

I have question about phone number formats. If I try to read call log on android device I get numbers in both formats. International and short versions. I always thought that this behaviour is somehow affected by format in which the contact is stored in contacts. But I am not sure anymore.

Is it possible that the phone is not getting the full format from provider? And that way it cannot give it to me? If this is the case, is there some specification under which conditions the provider is not providing the full format? For example if the call is inside the same country?

Or from provider the phone has always the full format and android is hiding it from me.

The ultimate state in which I need to get is every phone number in international format. But that is not possible for me. I dont have country information for every number.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think, that is provider dependent. Some transmit the international number, some the national one.

In the latter case, you can only to some best guess. I took the following approach for non international numbers:
use the country code of the current network provider. If that is not available
use the country code of the SIM card. If that is not available
use the country code of current locale.

Or in android code:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getActivity()
        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryISOCode = tm.getNetworkCountryIso().toUpperCase(Locale.US);
if (countryISOCode.isEmpty()) { // when not connected fall back to the SIM's country
    countryISOCode = tm.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase(Locale.US);
}
if (countryISOCode.isEmpty()) { // when even no SIM, get the countrycode from the locale
    countryISOCode = Locale.getDefault().getCountry();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how about the contact list? Does it count too? If I have the number in short format there, does the android than use that? Because based on observation we get number in both formats from one device.

Comment: I don't understand that completely. The phone number in the contact list is in the format, in which you have put it in...

Comment: Yes, user can put there any format, but we need to get international. The question is, whether the format in which user stored the number in contact list is somehow part of the process.